# Can't use bones of object rigged in Blender after importing into Unity

Tags: animation, rigging, unity

I am new to 3D Animation and Rigging and I have the following problem:

I want to **animate an Origami piece folding** in Unity and I managed to **rig** it accordingly in **Blender**. Unfortunately, the only way I found to do this is to use **9 armatures**, with one armature always having two child-bones. I tried to move all the bones to one armature, but it did not work even after unparenting and joining them.

Now, no matter how I export it to **Unity**, I can only make use of the two bones in the very first armature. All other **bones and armatures have no effect on the mesh**.

Does someone have an idea what is causing the problem or how to approch this in a smarter way?

The goal is that the user of my Unity application can see the Origami piece fold while being able to stop the folding animation at any time to take a closer look at the progess when trying to recreate the piece. When stopping the animation I would like everything to remain interactable so that the user can rotate the piece to see all sides of it.

I would be really thankful for anyone who is willing to help out. If you need any more info, I will gladly provide it.

Cheers :)
[image: Plane rigged with 9 Armatures]